# The Hahn-Banach theorem for Hilbert spaces follows from Riesz's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How does the Hahn-Banach theorem for Hilbert spaces follow from Riesz's representation theorem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Given a subspace $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$, and a continuous linear functional $f : M \to \mathbb{C}$, you can extend $f$ to a unique continuous linear functional $g : \overline{M} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Now, $\overline{M}$ is a Hilbert space, to there is $y \in \overline{M}$ such that
$$
g(x) = \langle x, y\rangle
$$
for all $x\in \overline{M}$.

Now write $h : H \to \mathbb{C}$ to be $x \mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$ and this extends $f$.

Comment: How to show the uniqueness?? @Prahlad

Comment: There's no uniqueness in the Hahn-Banach theorem. Also, if $H$ is finite-dimensional, there can be more than one continuous linear functional extending $f$, and the norm of a continuous linear extension can be larger than  $f$. To see this, extend a basis of $M$ to a basis of $H$, then extend $f$ to the basis of $H$ arbitrarily.

Comment: @Prahlad Is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space always a Hilbert space?